# Centering a Div on screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have this page that I started yesterday. It moves a div that is centered on the page away from the mouse. Everything works perfectly fine until I resize the page. The div doesn't go back to center until I move the mouse.

I've tried using the on screen resize, but can't seem to get it to work so I scraped it. I'm rather new to JS and Jquery things so I need a point in the right direction.

Here is the site I'm working on. http://afrohorse.netau.net/ I know it's bad practice, but for the sake of this page, I put CSS and JS all in the one page so that people could Right click -> View source, as I couldn't get a JSFiddle working.

Thanks in advance and if you need any clarification, let me know! :)

**EDITED TO ADD CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>qwerty</title>       
        <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

        body {
            background-image:url('cloud.jpg');
            background-repeat:repeat;
        }

        .box { 
            background-image:url('trans.png');
            background-repeat:repeat;
            width: 500px; 
            height: 200px; 
            position: absolute; 
            margin:100px -250px -100px 250px;
            bottom:50%;
            right:50%;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
            border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
            -webkit-box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 20px 1px #E0D9D9;
            box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 20px 1px #E0D9D9;

        }
        </style>

                <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).mousemove(function(e){
            var x = e.pageX-window.innerWidth/2;
            if (x <= 400) {
                x2=x*0.01
                x3=x2+window.innerWidth/2
                $('div.box').css({'right': x3}); 
            }
            var y = e.pageY-window.innerHeight/2;
            if (y <= 400) {
                y2=y*0.01
                y3=y2+window.innerHeight/2
                $('div.box').css({'bottom': y3}); 
            }
        });
    });

        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: @MateiMihai Code added!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set something to center the content as the window is resized:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $('div.box').css({'right': parseInt(window.innerWidth/2),
                      'bottom': parseInt(window.innerHeight/2)
                     });
});
```

Comment: This answer is perfect! I will mark it right as soon as it allows me to! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use https://api.jquery.com/resize/ already? That should enable you to reposition your div on resize.

Comment: I had mentioned that I tried that, but must've been doing something wrong. I'm new to jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

add css in your code

```
.box{
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

This will make your div in center from right to left. Use other css that you are currently using.

Comment: The div is centered on page load. I need to have it recenter itself after the page/window is resized.

Comment: First try above css and comment too :)

Comment: I already have it centered with my css. Your css does something that I already have done.

Comment: @Askanison4 I think you are correct. I was going to down vote it, but lack the reputation needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmBc8/)

```
function moveBox(e) {
    if (e === undefined) {
        e = { pageX: 0, pageY: 0 }
    }

    var x = e.pageX-window.innerWidth/2;
    if (x <= 400) {
        x2=x*0.01
        x3=x2+window.innerWidth/2
        $('div.box').css({'right': x3}); 
    }
    var y = e.pageY-window.innerHeight/2;
    if (y <= 400) {
        y2=y*0.01
        y3=y2+window.innerHeight/2
        $('div.box').css({'bottom': y3}); 
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).mousemove(function(e){
        moveBox(e);
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        moveBox();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative (without binding to the window.resize event) to force a floating DIV to re-center itself when the browser window is resized**

Without binding to the window.resize event

```
jQuery.fn.center = function() {
    var container = $(window);
    var top = -this.height() / 2;
    var left = -this.width() / 2;
    return this.css('position', 'absolute').css({ 'margin-left': left + 'px', 'margin-top': top + 'px', 'left': '50%', 'top': '50%' });
}
```

Usage:

```
$('#mydiv').center();
```

Comment: I already have it centered. I needed it to recenter on window resize. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, that works as well, but I have already accepted an answer. :)

Comment: @MathewMacLean I was trying to gave an alternative answer(Without binding to the window.resize event).. You can upvote it if it helps :)

Comment: @MathewMacLean hope you see my previous comment :)